# Getting "sudo: unknown uid xxx: who are you?" In Jenkins pipeline thats building its own container

Tags: docker, jenkins, sudo

I'm creating a Jenkins pipeline that creates its own container from centOS 
using `agent { dockerfile true }` then it calls a custom script using:

```
pipeline {
agent { dockerfile true }
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sh 'whoami'
            sh 'printenv'
            sh './rpmBuild.sh'
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then problem it that when it fails when calling any command with sudo, it gives `sudo: unknown uid xxx: who are you?`

Comment: what is `whoami` printing in the pipeline? Normally it's the jenkins user which is running it and which has no root permissions.

Comment: It prints `whoami: cannot find name for user ID 501 `

Comment: The script is executed from inside the Docker container? If it is, you can start your container with the root user?

Comment: I'm guessing that it is call from from the container because I defined my agent to be `dockerfile true.` I'm not sure how to start the container with the root user. I edited my code above with the entire jenkins file

Comment: Yes you are building an image from your dockerfile and creating a container from that image. The steps you execute are executed inside the image. I assume you are not a root user inside the container (so if you build your image from the dockerfile and `exec` inside the container you won't be root).  Actually it's a best practice to not run a container as root. But now you can't execute the sudo commands. You can edit your Dockerfile and run your container as root and execute the root commands in your script (without sudo) or you can add your script inside the dockerfile.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The UID xxx that jenkins was not able to recognize was jenkin's user id inside server/ubuntu system that was running jenkins and the pipeline was being run inside docker container where jenkins id was different. Hence, jenkins server id wasn't getting recognized inside docker.

So, here's what worked for me:
Changing from: JENKINS_USER=$NAME 
to: JENKINS_USER="root"
in /etc/default/jenkins

This can be verified from pipeline's console output that says right at the beginning:
$ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 ....

this 0:0 indicates its running as root user. 
When I was facing this issue, I had xxx:yyy instead of 0:0.
This xxx:yyy was the same as present for jenkins user in /etc/passwd inside server/ubuntu system running jenkins.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score -3):

Inside the container you need to have passwd, group and sudoers files that have the jenkins user.  The jenkins user needs to be setup to have password-less sudo (`%jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`).

One way is to setup the host's jenkins account properly, then run docker as:

```
docker run -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro -v /etc/sudoers.d:/etc/sudoers.d:ro ...
```